# Setting default heartbeat from WebSocketStompClient causes exceptions

Tags: spring, websocket, activemq-classic, stomp

We trying to use WebSocketStompClient to connect to the server implemented using spring websocket.

Our client is developed using spring 4.2.2 and works perfectly fine when the default heartbeat is not overriden.

However, I would like the client to send heartbeats in 2s intervals and therefore modified the client to set the default heart beat.

```
    WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(webSocketClient);
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler taskScheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    taskScheduler.afterPropertiesSet();
    long heartbeat[] = {2000, 10000};
    stompClient.setDefaultHeartbeat(heartbeat);
    stompClient.setTaskScheduler(taskScheduler); // for heartbeats, receipts
    String url = "ws://localhost:8080/Notify/app";
    StompSessionHandler handler = new MyStompHandler();
    ListenableFuture<StompSession>session = stompClient.connect(url, handler, "localhost", "8080");
```

This causes an exception

```
    Transport Error Connection closed
org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.ConnectionLostException: Connection closed
    at org.springframework.messaging.simp.stomp.DefaultStompSession.afterConnectionClosed(DefaultStompSession.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.messaging.WebSocketStompClient$WebSocketTcpConnectionHandlerAdapter.afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketStompClient.java:353)
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.onClose(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:143)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusEndpointWrapper.onClose(TyrusEndpointWrapper.java:1190)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusWebSocket.onClose(TyrusWebSocket.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.frame.CloseFrame.respond(CloseFrame.java:131)
```

We are using tyrus client 1.10, spring websocket 4.2.2 (for websocket client) and ActiveMQ 5.11.1 as the broker.

I have tried to set different heartbeat values, but all of them cause exceptions. 
I am not sure what is different when the client manually specifies the heartbeat.

Can someone please help?

Thanks.

Comment: did you find a solution? (seems I have a similar issue)

Comment: Yes, don't specify hearbeat intervals, use the defaults. Its 10s for ping/pong.

Comment: it might have something to do with [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22822). apparently the `WebSocketStompClient` passes these heartbeat parameters to some `StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler` which schedules them via `TcpConnection.onWriteInactivity(..)`. it seems that heartbeats are not send in a fixed interval.